# I'm trying to get python to read a .plist file

Tags: python, xml, plist

```
import binascii
import datetime
import re
import warnings
import io


def readPlist(C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\info):

    didOpen = 0
    if isinstance(pathOrFile, (str, unicode)):
        pathOrFile = open(pathOrFile)
        didOpen = 1
    p = PlistParser()
    rootObject = p.parse(pathOrFile)
    if didOpen:
        pathOrFile.close()
    return rootObject
```

I am very new to Python and i am trying to get this code to read a .plist file from a iPhone backup however it keeps coming up with unexpected character after line continuing character. I am using python 3.4 and running it on Windows 7. 
Any advise would be much appreciated

Comment: Isn't a `.plist` XML?

Comment: Then use an XML parser: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\info` pass as argument

Comment: That does not make any sense syntactically - do you mean e.g. `def readPlist(filename=r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\info'):`? Also, I don't see a definition of `PlistParser` anywhere.

Comment: Your code has multiple glaring issues e.g. pasting the file path into the header of the function makes no sense; PlistParser is not defined anywhere, and the way you attempt to open the file is ridiculous (look up _with statements_). I'd suggest you invest some more time into learning the language basics before attempting anything more complicated than "hello world".

Comment: `readPlist(C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\info)` this is a syntax error, at the very least you need quotes around a string, i.e. `readPlist("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\info")` but it still doesn't make sense as @jonrsharpe said

Comment: When you say "it keeps coming up with unexpected character after line continuing character", please post the exact error message and what you did to make it be printed (commands you run, input, etc). As others have commented, this code should not compile.

Answer (score 1):

Python includes a standard library for reading `.plist` files: https://docs.python.org/3/library/plistlib.html. Does this suffice?

```
import plistlib

with open(r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\info') as f:
    root = plistlib.load(f)
```